# Make google ads not clickable

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help with my website. I put an ad on my Flappy Bird like game and when you go to double click/tap, It starts highlighting the ad on the side. Is there a way to make the ad not highlight-able and/or clickable?

Comment: My guess is Google would not be happy if it weren't clickable...

Comment: That's a violation of [Adsense ToS](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms).

Comment: Remove the ad? No point having it there if the users can't click on it

Answer (score 0):

Think about the bigger problem.

You aren't preventing the default action of the event.

Make sure you call `event.preventDefault()` (`event` being a reference to the Event object), and `return false;` within your event handler - specifically the click handler - for your game.

Comment: I can tell you right now, I do not know where or how to use any of that. I can /barely/ modify existing code to my own liking.

Comment: If you would please do so, Look at the existing code and tell me what line to modify

http://fappy.13chag.net/flappybird.js

Comment: The way I understood his answer is the default action on double click is to highlight something. You need to write code that catches that and prevent it so that it will be able to just click on the screen freely

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following CSS rule to make the element containing the ad ignore all mouse interactions:

`pointer-events: none`

Though, as far as I know, this is forbidden by google adsense rules and they can ban you if you do this.

Comment: Okay, Since I am getting a lot of other negative feedback, I will explain what I want better. 

I want the ad to be clickable, But I dont want people to be able to highlight it when they doubleclick anywhere on the page

Comment: Also, The game will not work now. I need the game to be clickable, along with the ad. Now both cannot be clicked.